# Angular.js directive partially not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
app.directive('onFileSelected', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element[0]._HANDLE = scope.$eval(attrs.onFileSelected);
            element.bind('change', function() {
                element[0]._HANDLE();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And now, the following html:

```
<input type="file" name="{{container._id}}" on-file-selected="FileChanged" style="display: block !important;"/>
<div ng-repeat="item in container.items">
    <input type="file" name="{{container._id}}" on-file-selected="FileChanged" style="display: block !important;"/>
</div>
```

In my scope, i have defined the following method:

```
$scope.container = {
    _id: 0,
    items: [1,2,3,4,5]
};
$scope.FileChanged = function() {
    alert(this.files.length);
};
```

The Problem is now: This directive works only inside the ng-repeat, but not outside. Any ideas? Am I missing something? Outside of ng-repeat scope.$eval(attrs.onFileSelected); returns undefined.

Thank you!

Comment: Works for me without any issue here http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/ADukg/14372/ . Are you sure you have included the input inside the ng-controller's element?

Comment: Jes. Everything else around works fine. hmmm...